# Why isn't this php code removing the header and footer?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

This code came with the theme, its suppose to remove header and footer but doesn't do it. What can i add to it to make it work? Thanks

Im trying to remove it from the following page http://www.mobiletechrx.com/tuts3/ but it wont seem to render without these elements. Thanks!

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: No Header Or Footer Page
 */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


<section style="background-image: url()" class="banner alternate_page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main_cap">
      <div class="caption">
        <h2>
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="north_america default_page_with_sidebar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="fullwidth_part">
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="mobiletech_built mobiletech_built_cutom">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title_2">
      <h2></h2>

    </div>
    <ul>

    </ul>
  </div>
</section>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: When i have a look at the HTML source of the page you indicate, it starts directly with <section and end with </section>.  So I don't understand what you want. Can you explain in a better way?

Comment: I just want the footer and header removed, if this was html id do that quick but its wordpress and i dont know how to remove them. The php file i pasted is to remove the header and footer and only display the body but its not working. Im not much of an expert in php, sorry if im a bit vague.

Comment: This template might be theme-specific. The theme's header and footer files might check which template you're using, and hide certain elements. Are you using this file with its original name, in the theme that it came with?  Can you post the name of the theme, if it's a publicly available theme?

Answer (score 2):

You have `<?php get_header(); ?>` and `<?php get_footer(); ?>` in there - what do you expect - these tags are there to include the header and footer?

You can erase those, but you have to make sure to still maintain a complete and valid HTML page structure - especially the header.php contains also lots of "invisible" stuff that you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the header and footer by removing `<?php get_header(); ?>` and `<?php get_footer(); ?>` respectively as johannes suggested. But keep in mind that the `<head>` tags is contained in the header and the `<body>` and `<html>` tags are included in both the header and footer.

What you can do is copy the HTML structure from `header.php` up to the `<body>` tag and paste in the template file. The same goes for the footer, copy the HTML structure that you need in `footer.php` and paste it in the theme file. So it will look something like this:

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: No Header Or Footer Page
*/
?>
<!-- This is the start of the contents copied from header.php -->
<html>
    <head>
      <!-- Some Codes from your header.php-->
      <?php wp_head();?>
      <!-- Some scripts and styles-->
    </head>
    <body>
   <!-- This is maybe the end of the contents copied from header.php -->
   <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
     <section style="background-image: url()" class="banner alternate_page">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="main_cap">
           <div class="caption">
            <h2>
            </h2>
           </div>
         </div>
        </div>
     </section>
     <!-- Some codes -->
     <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
     <!-- Some of the contents copied from the footer.php. That includes the scripts called outside the wp_footer action hook and such.-->
     <?php wp_footer();?>
   </body>
</html>
```